# Plotting $\frac{\partial C}{\partial u}\Big|_{u=0.5}$ where $C(u,v)= \min\left[ u^{0.0325}v, uv^{-0.1018} \right]$

Tags: plotting

As the title suggests, I want to plot $\frac{\partial C}{\partial u}\Big|_{u=0.5}$ for the function $C(u,v)= \min\left[ u^{0.0325}v, uv^{-0.1018} \right]$. I had a great difficulty to do this task. I tried SymPy library in python but since there is minimum function it couldn't plot. I also tried to use piecewise function to avoid using minimum function but I got the error,

> invalid value encountered in double_scalars.

I hadn't any experience with Mathematica. So I'm wondering if it is possible to do it with the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be use partial derivative `Derivative[1, 0]` or `D[..., u]`.

```
c[u_, v_] := Min[u^0.0325 v, u v^-0.1018]
Plot[Derivative[1, 0][c][.5, v], {v, 0, 2}]
Plot[D[c[u, v], u] /. u -> .5 // Evaluate, {v, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Or we can at first calculate the `Grad` and select the first part.

```
Plot[D[Min[u^0.0325 v, u v^-0.1018], {{u, v}}] /. u -> .5 // First // 
  Evaluate, {v, 0, 2}]
Plot[Grad[Min[u^0.0325 v, u v^-0.1018], {u, v}] /. u -> .5 // First // 
  Evaluate, {v, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Note exponent in first argument is 0.0325 not 0.325

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just for illustrative purposes:

```
c[u_, v_] := Min[u ^0.0325 v, u v^-0.1018]
p1 = Plot3D[c[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), 
   MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}, Mesh -> {{0.5}}, 
   PlotLabel -> "C(u,v)"];
dc[r_, s_] := D[c[u, v], u] /. {u -> r, v -> s}
p2 = Plot3D[Evaluate@dc[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   Mesh -> {{0.5}}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(∂C\), \(∂u\)]\)"];
p3 = Plot[dc[0.5, v], {v, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(∂C\), \
\(∂u\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(|\), \(u = 0.5\)]\)"];
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[
    Evaluate@(D[Min[u^0.325 v, u v^-0.1018], {u}, {v}] /. u -> .5), 
    {v, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Etemon  The answer is wrong. It is not a Partial Derivative. For example, `D[u*v,{u,v}]` is wrong.

Comment: Both `D[u*v, {u}, {v}]` or `D[u*v,{u,v}]` is wrong here.