# Given the plot of $(v, f(v))$ how to scale horizontal axis with $v \to 87\sqrt{-2\log(1 - v)})$, while keeping the vertical axis unchanged?

Tags: plotting

In my [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295118/plotting-frac-partial-c-partial-u-big-u-0-5-where-cu-v-min-left) @herbertfederer provided a script to plot $\frac{\partial C}{\partial u}\Big|_{u=0.5}$ where $C(u,v)= \min\left[ u^{0.0325}v, uv^{-0.1018} \right]$,

```
c[u_, v_] := Min[u^0.0325 v, u v^-0.1018]
Plot[D[c[u, v], u] /. u -> .5 // Evaluate, {v, 0, 1}]
```

Here I modified the range of $v$ to $(0,1)$. Now it plots a function say $f(v)$ for the horizontal $v$ values. I need to assign $87\sqrt{-2\log(1 - v)}$ to $v$ and plot the function based on this new horizontal axis. So I tried,

```
c[u_, v_] := Min[u^0.0325 v, u v^-0.1018]
Plot[D[c[u, v], u] /. u -> 0.5 /. v -> (87*Sqrt[-2*Log[1 - v]]) // Evaluate, {v, 0, 0.9999}]
```

I choose "{v, 0, 0.9999}" in order to $\log(1-v)$ be defined. But after running the script I got errors.  Can you help me to fix the issue?

Comment: Try ParametricPlot

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Can you elaborate on that? I'm new to mathematica.

Comment: Did you modify the question? I remember `v->h[x]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes I realized my explanation was not accurate and found a better way to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The new v looks like:

```
Plot[-87*Sqrt[-2*Log[1 - v]], {v, 0, 0.9999}]
```

[image]

Now rise this to the power of : -0.1018:

```
Table[(-87*Sqrt[-2*Log[1 - v]])^-0.1018, {v, 0, 0.9, 0.1}]

{ComplexInfinity, 0.6522 - 0.215998 I, 0.627758 - 0.207903 I, 
 0.612949 - 0.202998 I, 0.601844 - 0.199321 I, 0.592567 - 0.196248 I, 
 0.584208 - 0.19348 I, 0.576145 - 0.19081 I, 0.567696 - 0.188011 I, 
 0.55744 - 0.184615 I}
```

You see that the new v is complex.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I wrongly put an extra minus sign in the expression. It should be ```87*Sqrt[-2*Log[1 - v]]```. Thanks for detecting it.

Comment: For example assume the map of $v=0.4$ with above function is 90 and assume the original graph of partial derivative gives $f(0.4)= 0.3$  I'm looking for a plot that gives $f(90)=0.3$. And this pattern holds for other value of $v\in[0,1)$. And I want to scale only horizontal axis by the pre-defined function.

Comment: I am a bit confused because you have 2 variables: u, v. Are you looking for: f'( Inverse(f)(x)) ?

Comment: The variable u in the original function C(u,v) is only used for partial derivative and then plugging a specific u, i.e $\large\frac{\partial C}{\partial u}\Big|_{u=0.5}$ And this gives a function based on only the variable v. Now I want to transform the horizontal axis of  the plot of this function the way I stated in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I take it that you are looking for:  `f'( Inverse(f)(x) )`.

Lets set u=0.1. Then the derivative is is defined for x>0. However, the inverse function creates a problem. Look at:

```
Plot[c[0.1, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The inverse function c takes the values between 0.145 and 0.1 twice. Therefore, it it is not unique, but double valued. Therefore, you have to restrict the definition range to make the function single valued..